# Handle click in popupwindow with list view while maintaining focus on EditText

Tags: android, android-listview, popupwindow

In my app I have an `EditText` where the user can input text and when the user inputs a special character (#, @ etc) I show a `PopupWindow` with autocompletion suggestions that I fetch from a server.

Originally I used a `ListPopupWindow` for this and that worked as expected, but since that is only available in API 11, I can not use it on Gingerbread devices.

The problem I have is that if I use `PopupWindow.setFocusable(true)` I can indeed select items from my list, but then the user cannot continue typing without closing the popup. If I don't use `PopupWindow.setFocusable(true)` I can only select items on my Nexus 4 running KitKat.

I have also looked at the `AutoCompleteTextView`, but I am not sure if this is what I am looking for.

How can both allow the user to click on items in the listview and continue typing without dismissing the popup?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi. Did you try `editText.requestFocus()` after `PopupWindow.setFocusable(true)`?

Comment: @user2819864 Yes. This makes the popup clickable but dismisses the popup when I continue typing.

Comment: Are you doing it in this order? 
`popUp= new PopupWindow(layout, width-40, height-(height/4), true);
popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);`